# AirFlow sensors not triggering child task when parent DAG is done

Tags: python, airflow

I am having a hard time trying to work with sensors here. I want to trigger `my_final_task` after all other DAGs are done.

I always get a timeout by the sensors even though the child DAGs succeeded.

Please note that none of those DAGs have a schedule. they are being triggered manually by me now.

I am using 1.10.14 that's why `wait_for_completion` is not an option here since it doesn't wait for the DAG to complete.

Thank you!

```
dags = [
    "dag_1",
    "dag_2",
    "dag_3",
]

default_args = {
    "depends_on_past": False,
    "retries": 1,
    "retry_delay": timedelta(minutes=1),
    "retry_exponential_backoff": True,
    ...
}

with DAG(
        "my_sensor_dag",
        schedule_interval=None,
        default_args=default_args,
        max_active_runs=1,
        catchup=False,
) as dag:
    my_final_task = ...

    for dag_to_run in dags:
        dummy_dag_task = TriggerDagRunOperator(
            task_id=dag_to_run,
            trigger_dag_id=dag_to_run,
            execution_date="{{ execution_date }}"
        )

        sensor_task = ExternalTaskSensor(
            task_id="sensor_" + dag_to_run,
            external_dag_id=dag_to_run,
            soft_fail=True,
            external_task_id=None,
            timeout=60 * 20,
            mode="reschedule"
        )

        dummy_dag_task >> sensor_task >> my_final_task
```

Comment: Hey @briba right off the bat, I notice your task dummy_dag_task has an ID that has already been used by a DAG. I am referring to the line dummy_dag_task.task_id = dag_to_run. I don't think that's right, no? May you also post the logs for your 'my_sensor_dag' run to help you debug?

Comment: Also curious what happens if you replace the line : dummy_dag_task >> sensor_task >> my_final_task with: sensor_task >> my_final_task? The task sensor operator can have a sensor for a DAG that has not yet run so it need not be set upstream of the trigger DAG run task.